# How can I 0-pad a number by a variable amount when formatting with std::fmt?

Tags: rust

I'm looking to 0-pad a string before I display it to the user, e.g.

```
let x = 1234;
println!("{:06}", x); // "001234"
```

However, I'd like the length of the output string to be variable, e.g. it could be set by a command line parameter from the user:

```
let x = 1234;
let width = 6;
println!("{:0*}", width, x); //fails to compile
// error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'*'`
```

Unlike precision, it doesn't seem that 0-padding supports the `*` for specifying a width.

I'm not looking for solutions that involve manually padding, because it seems awkward to re-implement part of `std::fmt`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the `:0_` format specifier with a variable:

```
println!("{:0width$}", x, width = width); // prints 001234
```

[Here it is running in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=c2a09c2ead5466278422b8b2e8d7cb71&version=stable)

Likewise, if `width <= 4`, it just prints `1234`. If `width = 60`, it prints:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001234
```

The format arguments also support ordinals, thus this also works:

```
println!("{:01$}", x, width);
```

The [documentation for std::fmt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax) has a rundown of the various parameters and modifiers the `print_!` macros support.

Comment: Just a note: this also words with ordinals: `println!("{:01$}", x, width)`.  Also, might be worth linking to the [`std::fmt` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax) that spell all this out.

Comment: Thanks @DK. I have added your suggested improvements.

Comment: Useful examples can be found here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#fillalignment